# Java: Mongo fails to assert the right number of documents inserted

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have a following test

```
    @Test
    public void testPutDocuments() throws Exception {
        final DBObject document01 = new DBObject();
        document01.put("uniqueId", "001");
        document01.put("rv", "values");
        document01.put("pv", "values");

        final DBObject document02 = new DBObject();
        document02.put("uniqueId", "002");
        document02.put("rv", "values");
        document02.put("pv", "values");

        final DBObject document03 = new DBObject();
        document03.put("uniqueId", "003");
        document03.put("rv", "values");
        document03.put("pv", "values");

        final List<DBObject> documents = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
        documents.add(document01);
        documents.add(document02);
        documents.add(document03);

        mongoRule.getMongoService().putDocuments(documents);
        assertEquals(3, mongoRule.getDatabase().getCollection("test").getCount());
    }
```

Where `mongoRule` is a rule which connects to database, provides `MongoService`(a wrapper written to mongo client)

*MongoService related methods*

```
public void putDocument(@Nonnull final DBObject document) {
    LOGGER.info("inserting document - " + document.get("uniqueId"));
    mongo.getDB(database).getCollectionFromFull(getCollectionName(document)).insert(document);
}

public void putDocuments(@Nonnull final List<DBObject> documents) {
    for (final DBObject document : documents) {
        putDocument(document);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :3
Actual   :1
```

Now, if I do this

```
  mongoRule.getMongoService().putDocuments(documents);
  Thread.sleep(1000); 
  assertEquals(3, mongoRule.getDatabase().getCollection("contract").getCount());
```

I see no error.

**Question:**
a.) Why sleeping a thread for a second helped in getting a right number. isn't it a concurrency related issue? What if two threads are trying to put same documents where as document has to be unique.
b.) How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: This question was also asked & answered on the mongodb-user google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/jyvMkDFVous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered here - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/jyvMkDFVous